# Is a parameter pack a template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, terminology

cppreference writes that a template parameter pack is a template parameter:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack

Is it true? For example, is it correct to write something like this:

```
template<typename... Ts>
class MyClass {
    std::unique_ptr<Ts...> m_data;
};
```

Comment: Think about it for a moment... With the code you show you could do `MyClass<int, double, MyOtherStructure> my_object;`. That would mean you had `std::unique_ptr<int, double, MyOtherStructure> m_data;`. That's not valid.

Comment: You have `...` in a wrong place: must be `template<typename... T>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a parameter pack is a valid template *parameter*, to use in a *declaration*. But when a template is *instantiated*, it is replaced with a list of actually supplied template *arguments*, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters

E.g. in your example `MyClass<int>` will contain `std::unique_ptr<int>`, `MyClass<int, MyDeleter>` will contain `std::unique_ptr<int, MyDeleter>` and `MyClass<int, MyDeleter, Foo>` will cause a compiler error "wrong number of template arguments", because `std::unique_ptr` may have at most two of them.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, think of it as if you wrote down a sequence of types when instantiating `MyClass` (should be `template<typename... T> class MyClass;` btw), and then this sequence was accurately copied into `std::unique_ptr`'s instantiation. `std::unique_ptr` accepts up to two parameters, and the second one is something special, so not everything would work:

```cpp
int main() {
        MyClass<int> this_compiles;
        MyClass<int, std::default_delete<int>> as_does_this;
        //MyClass<int, double, char> this_does_not;
        //MyClass<> this_neither;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers, I would like to add an answer to this question from the perspective of the standard.

Per [[temp.variadic]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.variadic#1):

> A template parameter pack is a template parameter that accepts zero or
>   more template arguments.

So yeah, a template parameter pack is a template parameter. The code snippet you posted is correct.